# Weird formatting of properties in Resharper 8

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-2013, resharper-8.1

I have a problem with Resharper 8.
Everytime I declare a property in my code, Resharper completely ruins my code:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProp { get; set; }
}
```

will be reformatted to:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProp { get; set; }
}
}
```

And if I declare "small" properties like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProp { get { return 1; } }
}
```

it will be reformatted to:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int MyProp
    {
        get { return 1; }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix the first case and is there a way to tell Resharper how long a single-lined property is allowed to be?
If I have very short properties I don't want them to spread over multiple lines.

If it is not fixable how can I tell Resharper to use Visual Studio's formatting in that cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make sure 'short' properties get formatted on the same line,

go to ReSharper -> options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping

and on the right-pane , scroll all the way down to 'Other',

then tick the 'Place Simple property/indexer/event declaration on single line' option.

You would see the preview window changing from

```
class C
{
    private int Property
    {
        get { return x; }
        set { x = value; }
    }
}
```

to

```
class C
{
    private int Property { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
}
```